# Javascript: why here used preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, events, preventdefault

I've been looking at some code posted by someone and I don't know why he used preventDefault here. Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you very much.
https://codepen.io/Sylvia31/pen/eygvVm

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

   **e.preventDefault();**

   responseContainer.innerHTML = '';
   searchedForText = searchField.value;
   const imgRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   imgRequest.onload = addImage;
   imgRequest.onerror = function (err) {
      requestError(err, 'image');
   };
```

Comment: It's to prevent the browser from submitting a form.

Comment: @ Pointy but why the browser need to prevent submitting a form?

Comment: Probably because the submit action reloads the page

Comment: That code is performing an HTTP request via `XMLHttpRequest()`, so the form submission is not necessary. Now, why the code is set up this way is another question, but you did not post enough context for anybody to know the whole story.

Comment: An ajax or httpRequest mostly doesnt need a page reload. So to avoid a page reloading to a action url you use prevent default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from the [`Event.preventDefault()` MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) that :

> `preventDefault()` method tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

And with a form the default action of clicking the submit button would be to `submit` the form and redirect the user to the action page defined in the form, and the use of `preventDefault()` in the `submit` event handler can stop the form submission.

In your case  `e.preventDefault()` is used here to stop the form default submission behavior and execute an alternative block of code, which is in this case an `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, preventDefault is used to cancel or stop the normal behavior of the event. Like preventing a submit button from submitting, or preventing a link from redirecting.

Here, the person could have used preventDefault to prevent the checkbox from submiting.